# Remove ip from json response in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have rest api in Laravel like below:

```
{
    "id": 17,
    "title": "Devnet",
    "slug": "devnet",
    "content": "sfdf",
    "technology_id": 1,
    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/posts/1570907475IMG_20171229_123822.jpg|uploads/posts/1570907475IMG_20171229_133927.jpg|uploads/posts/1570907475IMG_20180319_124721.jpg",
    "link": "https://www.somelink.com/in/test/",
    "deleted_at": null,
}
```

I need to remove local ip (`127.0.0.1:8000`) address from all responses.For example in image I have 3 files but in code which I present you can see 3 links and only one of them have full path.

Actually in DB they don't have full path.All of them posted to DB without local ip like this `uploads/posts/image_name.jpg`.In model creation I check with **dd** all my images without local ip (`127.0.0.1:8000`).Only `uploads/posts/image_name.jpg`.

How I store data to db in controller:

```
    $images = array();
    if ($files = $request->file('image')) {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $name =  "uploads/posts/" . time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move("uploads/posts", $name);
            $images[] = $name;
        }
    }

    // validating in here ..
    if I dd($images) in here it show me 3 array of images without local ip.

    $project= Project::create([
        "title" => $request->title,
        "content" => $request->content,
        'image' =>  implode("|", $images),
        "technology_id" => $request->technology_id,
        "slug" => str_slug($request->title),
        "tags" => "required",
        "link" => $request->link
    ]);
```

Also my main `Controller` which returns `json` to view nothing special.

```
public function index(){
    $result = Project::with('something','something')->get();
    return response()->json($result);
}
```

Project model

```
class Project extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        "title","content","image","technology_id","link","slug"
    ];

    public function getImageAttribute($image){
        return asset($image);
    }
    protected $dates = ["deleted_at"];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're showing all your code? Nothing in the code you've shown would produce this output. Is there an mutator or accessor function on `$project->images` perhaps?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yup I show all code.No not have any mutator or accessor function

Comment: Yes, you do. `getImageAttribute` is an accessor function, and it's the cause.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank's please write a answer I will accept it.Thank's a lot one more time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [accessor function](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) is your culprit:

```
public function getImageAttribute($image){
    return asset($image);
}
```

The `asset` function [returns an absolute URL](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-asset), and it additionally won't have any clue what to do with your imploded array of images.